# Missing Gem in Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, passenger

My Rails 2.3.8 app couldn't startup because of a missing gem: friendly_id. I got the following error message:

```
Missing these required gems: friendly_id ~> 3.2.1 You're running: ruby 1.8.7.253 at /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/ruby rubygems 1.3.7 at /home/development/.gem/ruby/1.8, /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8 Run `rake gems:install` to install the missing gems.
```

where `development` is the user I am running the app.

I found that in my local `/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` I was able to install the gem into this directory using the `sudo gem install friendly_id` command.

But I noticed that in the path for Passenger to retrieve the gem from: `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` does not have the `friendly_id` gem. I couldn't run the command without `sudo` though.

Now I know I gotta install the `friendly_id` gem into the `/opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems` directory, but I couldn't figure out how.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to install missing gem into the required directory using this command:

```
sudo /opt/ruby-enterprise-1.8.7-2010.02/bin/gem install <<<gem-name-here>>>
```